# Dynamically change custom converter for nested type

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net, deserialization

Due to a schema change I need to control the deserialization of property b depending on the API version or client version from the controller level.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string a { get; set; }

    // old: public string b { get; set; }
    public string[] b { get; set; }
}
```

I'm looking to implement a custom converter to write string[] as a single string if the version is old.

When constructing the response, I'm deserializing a parent model and want to use the custom converter only on this one property.

```
public class ParentModel
{
    public MyModel myModel { get; set; }
}
```

This means an attribute for b wouldn't work. How can I implant such a custom converter on demand for just one property (custom converters switch on by a type, not a property name)?

Answer (score 1):

Check bellow Code

```
public class ParentModelJSONConverter : JavaScriptConverter
    {

        public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Serializable only");
        }

        public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            ParentModel myobj = obj as ParentModel;
            if (myobj != null)
            {
                // Add your conditions
                result.Add("MyKeyName", myobj.myModel);
            }
            return result;
        }

        public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
        {
            get { return new Type[] { typeof(ParentModel) }; }
        }
    }
```

To use above code

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.RegisterConverters(new JavaScriptConverter[] { new ParentModelJSONConverter() });
String json = serializer.Serialize(objParentModel);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I prefer to stick to Json.NET and just deserialize the model manually.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing the following manual conversion. Since it's a schema change, the old model can be easily hardcoded:

```
public class CustomConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var o = (MyModel)value;

        writer.WriteStartObject();

        writer.WritePropertyName("a");
        writer.WriteValue(o.a);

        writer.WritePropertyName("b");
        writer.WriteValue(o.b[0]);

        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(MyModel);
    }

    //...
}
```

}